Angular frequency vector, when explaining the motion of a wave
The wave number $|k|$ results as the magnitude of the wave vector $k$. Is there an analogous vector from which the angular frequency $\omega$ results when the magnitude is formed? If yes, how can you imagine it physically? If not, why is it nonsense and does this theoretical quantity/vector exist in mathematics?

Yes, angular velocity vector is scaled cross-product of position and tangential velocity vectors : $$ \boldsymbol \omega = r^{-2} (\boldsymbol r \times \boldsymbol v) .$$
So that $ |\boldsymbol \omega| = \omega = 2 \pi \nu .$

Sure, it's uncommon and I don't think I've seen it, but it is possible.
The $k$-vector arises when you look at Fourier transforms of 2- or 3D data. For example, let $\phi(x,y)$ be some field that depends on $x$ and $y$. The Fourier transform is given by
$$\hat \phi(k_x,k_y)=\iint\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,e^{i(k_xx+k_yy)}\phi(x,y)$$
Note that this would be the same if you first transformed $x$ and then transformed $y$.
So, since $\omega$ is the "conjugate" variable of time, we just need to have a quantity that depends on two (or more) time variables. I can't think of an example, but there should be ones. The physical interpretation is then similar to the $k$-vector.

Thank you. That means, because the time is only going forward and backwards (1 dimension), there is no need for many components of the scalar ω

Yes, there is. Angular frequency $\omega$ is the magnitude of the pseudovector angular velocity $\boldsymbol{\omega}$. Its direction is normal to the plane of rotation. The sense is determined conventionally by the right-hand rule. For example (Wikimedia Commons):

